# Schur's lemma for sheaves with different reduced Hilbert polynomials

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, vector-bundles, moduli-spaces, sheaf-theory

Recall Schur's Lemma for Gieseker-semistable sheaves, in particular the injectivity statement:

> Let $\psi : F \to G$ be a morphism of Gieseker-semistable sheaves. If $p(F)=p(G)$ and $F$ is stable, then $\psi$ is either injective or zero.

where $p(-)$ is the reduced Hilbert polynomial. My question is: is there a variant/similar statement for sheaves with *different* Hilbert polynomials?

I have heard that one can use $p_{-}(-)$ and $p_{+}(-)$ coming from the Harder-Narasimhan filtration. Does anyone have a reference for this/know the statement? In the book of Huybrechts-Lehn, there is the statement $p_-(F)>p_+(G)$ implies $\psi=0$, but there doesn't seem to be a statement regarding injectivity.

Thanks!

Comment: When $\mathscr F$ is stable (or even semistable), we have $p_-(\mathscr F) = p(\mathscr F) = p_+(\mathscr F)$, so $p(\mathscr F) > p_+(\mathscr G)$ implies $\psi = 0$. I don't know what you mean by "there doesn't seem to be a statement regarding injectivity" ― the conclusion is actually *stronger* in the case of different slopes. (Compare this with Schur's lemma for representations of finite groups, where there are no nonzero maps between different irreducible characters.)

Comment: By contrast, if $\mathscr F$ and $\mathscr G$ are stable but $p(\mathscr F) < p(\mathscr G)$, then there are many nonzero maps $\mathscr F \to \mathscr G$, which may even have kernels. For example, if $\mathscr F$ is stable of rank $2$ and $s \in H^0(\mathscr F^\vee(d))$ for $d \gg 0$, then $s$ gives a map $\mathscr F \to \mathcal O(d)$ whose kernel must be a line bundle.

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn Thanks for your comments. I suppose my question is whether there's a statement like: $p_-(F)=p_+(G)$ and $F$ stable implies $\psi$ is injective or zero? Because if this were true, then instead of requiring $p(F)=p(G)$ for injectivity, I suppose we could require $p(F)=p_+(G)$

Comment: Ah, that's certainly true, and follows from the stated version together with the version in my first comment. Indeed, if $0 \to \mathscr G_+ \to \mathscr G \to \mathscr G' \to 0$ is the semistable subobject of highest slope (for whatever slope function you're using), then $\operatorname{Hom}(\mathscr F, \mathscr G') = 0$ so $\psi$ lands in $\mathscr G_+$, which is semistable with $p(\mathscr G_+) = p(\mathscr F)$.

Comment: I see, thanks for your help!